# Angular/Javascript : for loop to init a form. How to write it correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm doing a form and I want to do a loop according to my matches.length like this :

pronoPlayer0:['',Validators.required]

pronoPlayer1:['',Validators.required]

pronoPlayer2:['',Validators.required]

I don't know how to right correctly the "i", currently with the code bellow, I have the following error : error TS1005: ',' expected.

```
  initForm(){
    this.pronoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      for(let i=0; i<this.matches.length; i++){
      ["pronoPlayer"+i]: ['',Validators.required]
    }});
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pronoPlayer[i]` is done to access an array or property of an object. So, `pronoPlayer[i]: 'something'` is not a valid syntax, and hence you get the error.

Since your intention is to create dynamic keys here, do this instead:

`["pronoPlayer"+i] = ['',Validators.required],`

**UPDATE**

You need to create a correct structure thorough `for..loop` and pass it in inside `this.formBuilder.group(...);` Something like this:

```
   var obj = {}
   for(let i=0; i<this.matches.length; i++){
        obj["pronoPlayer"+i] = ['',Validators.required];
    }
this.pronoForm = this.formBuilder.group(obj);
```

Comment: I updated my question, I still have a lot of error now with some ',' expected, ':' expected, ';' expected. I put my for inside the this.formBuilder.group() as well

Comment: Yup exactly. That's what you need to do.

Comment: See if you're passing the param in `this.formBuilder.group` correctly. If need be, take the for loop out and create a structure and pass it.

Comment: How do I create a structure to pass it ?